# Up button doesn't work correctly in android 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-activity, android-navigation, up-button

I have a main activity and a child activity. I am using up button in child activity to return to main activity. In my activity I have some animation that I don't want to start it again when I return to it form child activity. So here is home action in child activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

And here is manifest:

```
 <activity
      android:name=".ChildActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >

      <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
          android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

When I run it on **LG nexus 5** with **android 4.4.4** it works fine but in **Xperia arc** with **android 4.0.4** it starts the animation each time I return to main activity. What's the solution?

**Update:**

I can achieve what I want using one of these ways:

1- Just calling `finish()` when up is pressed.

2- Using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` when adding flag to intent.

But I want to know what causes this difference in behavior in android 4.4.4 and 4.0.4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add your comments to your question, this way when people read it can easily understand the situation:-)

Answer (score 0):

Per [Providing Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp), you can use `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` rather than constructing an `Intent` yourself as this will handle the flags correctly to return to the parent activity.

Comment: It causes both devices to start animation when I return to main activity.

Comment: Right, Up and Back (what is done by `finish()`) are different operations: back is simply closing the current screen and going to where the user came from while Up involves creating a semantic, consistent parent state. If you don't have `singleTop` on your parent activity's manifest entry, then you'll see it totally recreating the parent activity and the animation you see.